# Website debugger to find parameters passed on user submission

Tags: asp.net, httprequest

I was wondering if there was a way to see what parameters or other information is passed upon submitting a form from another website of which you don't have any of the server code.

Here is the page I am trying to debug - https://umbc.t2hosted.com/cit/index.aspx.

When I put information into the fields, and submit it, there is not added data to the url like there would be in a regular get request. Is there any tool that can help me find out what parameters are actually passed so that I may simulate user requests with a program?

Thank you in advance with you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [debugger proxy such as fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to see all the data that is sent from your machine to the website when doing the query.

This will allow you to see the HTTP messages sent from your browser to the website. Once you've seen and understood how the message are sent, it should be relatively easy to reproduce them with another program.